# How to find out the full directory of a file in Android phone to be used with fstream?

Tags: android, c++

I am trying to test a very basic c++ code in CppDroid app to create a text file on my Android phone (Huawei P20pro). But it doesn't seem to work. I think the problem is with the file directory. Can someone let me know how to get the real full directory of a file/folder in Android phone?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    ofstream NewFile;

    NewFile.open("/Internal Storage/CppDroid/projects/project_dec23a/Gyrocopter.txt");

    NewFile << "This is a file about a gyrocopter. \n";

    NewFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Can someone let me know how to get the real full directory of a file/folder ` That is impossible if you only know the name of the file or the folder. The paths to them can be different as there are many storage locations possible.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I might have used the wrong word 'script'. I have changed it now...

Comment: Yes, to find out the path to specific storage location of a file is the problem.  Can you tell me how to find out about it?

Comment: Have you requested permission to write files?

Comment: `That is impossible if you only know the name of the file or the folder. The paths to them can be different as there are many storage locations possible. `